# Does yii2 beforeSave() get called for selects too?

Tags: php, yii2

If i run the code below which is just a simple select of 4 specific rows from a default yii2 method somehow beforeSave() gets called like it's some kind of an update or insert.
Is this behaviour normal?

**From the official docs**
This method is called at the beginning of inserting or updating a record.

The default implementation will trigger an EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT event when $insert is true, or an EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE event if $insert is false.

**Model**

```php
class Users extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
```

**beforeSave() inside model**

```php
$this->modified = Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime('now', 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**controller method**

```php
public function actionUsers() {
    $allOfEm = new Users();
    return array('status' => 'ok', 'users' => $allOfEm::findAll([1,2,4,5]));
}
```

I would expect beforeSave() not to run, what is going on?

Comment: How do you know that User::beforeSave() get called?

Comment: It should not run on selects. If this is your case there must be something doing the save.

Comment: I know it runs because if I check the "modified" column for IDs 1,2,4,5 it gets updated

Comment: Do you guys have any ideas of where beforeSave could get called? What should i look for? ->save() ? Or does it get called in some other situations too?

Comment: Easiest way to check what is causing this is to add a breakpoint in `beforeSave()` and run this action through xdebug.

Comment: I found it already ! Bizley thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If it helps out someone else It was obviously 100% my fault, I had ->save() inside afterFind() which does get triggered on selects so that then triggers the beforeSave() method

@Bizley pointed me in the right direction